# How interpretation MS-EMF Header object properties - Bounds, Frame, Device and Millimeters?

Tags: rendering, specifications, .emf

I'm implement rendering [MS-EMF](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/en-en/library/cc230514.aspx) to raster image tool.
Parser by specification work's fine. But i have interpretatioin [2.2.9 Header Object](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd240211.aspx) properties when rendering problem, not enough information in the specification.

To convert from `LOGICAL` to `DEVICE` coordinates use current MapMode. How to interpret them (especially interesting `MM_ISOTROPIC` and `MM_ANISOTROPIC`) can look at `gdi`, for example [here](http://wvware.sourceforge.net/caolan/mapmode.html).

Now, i'm trying to specify the position and size of the whole image:

```
var minPoint = new PointF(header.Bounds.Left, header.Bounds.Top);
var maxPoint = new PointF(header.Bounds.Right, header.Bounds.Bottom);

float imageWidth = maxPoint.X - minPoint.X;
float imageHeight = maxPoint.Y - minPoint.Y;

float shiftX = -minPoint.X;
float shiftY = -minPoint.Y;

var globalCanvas = new CanvasClass(options.PageWidth, options.PageHeight);
globalCanvas.RenderTransform = new DrMatrix(1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0);

float scaleX = options.PageWidth / (maxPoint.X + shiftX);
float scaleY = options.PageHeight / (maxPoint.Y + shiftY);
float minCommonScale = Math.Min(scaleX, scaleY);

if (minCommonScale > Epsilon)
{
    globalCanvas.RenderTransform.Scale(minCommonScale, minCommonScale);
}

globalCanvas.RenderTransform.Translate(shiftX, shiftY);
```

but i don't understand how to use all properties - Bounds, Frame, Device and Millimeters - and the result image is stretched or not correct scaling or position of the image is not correct.

**How them interpret?**

**Example 1.**
[emf file](http://drive.google.com/file/d/0BzWy7mV3th5AWGY5cXNJcXFyTWM)
header:

```
Bounds: (0, 0) - (579, 429)
Frame:  (0, 0) - (10000, 10000)
Device: 1855, 1034
Millimeters:    320, 240
```

and total 4 records:

```
SelectObject(hDC, (HGDIOBJ)GRAY_BRUSH);
Ellipse(hDC, 0, 0, 99, 99);
SelectObject(hDC, (HGDIOBJ)BLACK_BRUSH);
Ellipse(hDC, 480, 330, 579, 429);
```

result:
[image: ex1-result]
but we must see [ex1-ethalon](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1NiBG.png)
*Interestingly, viewers display ehalon incorrect, except the windows standard viewer:* 
[image: ex1-windows-internal-vewer-ethalon]

**Example 2.**
[emf file](http://drive.google.com/file/d/0BzWy7mV3th5AVDU3b29kSmZyY00)
header:

```
Bounds: (960, 210) - (3396, 2429)
Frame:  (6772, 1481) - (23969, 17143)
Device: 2892, 4125
Millimeters:    204, 291
```

result (incomplete rendering yet): [image: ex2-result-incomplete-rendering]
but we see ethalon (attention on the image position): [image: ex2-ethalon]